# Classes brought from Team A and Team B polluting the same global namespace

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am new to Tailwind CSS but there is something that confuses me.

Let's run a scenario:

**Team A**

- builds a UI component library using TailwindCSS (Button, Forms, Dialog, etc)
- publish NPM package where exports `index.ts` and `theme/tailwind.css`

**Team B**

- `npm install` Team A library. Imports `theme/tailwind.css` into their application `main.ts` (entry point).

At this point, their `main.ts` should have

```
import { Button } from '@team-a/ui`
import '@team-a/ui/theme/tailwind.css` // tailwind classes coming from Team A
import `./theme/main.css` // tailwind CSS global file belonging to Team B
```

At this point in time, in the `<style>` tags in the head, we will have classes brought from Team A and Team B, polluting the same global namespace.

How do you get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few ways to avoid this, but if both teams uses tailwind there should not be any issue. unless you have custom CSS that for example overrides custom properties at the :root.

Regardless here a few ways to avoid clashing CSS styles.

1. use [@layers](https://css-tricks.com/css-cascade-layers/),
2. Scope the CSS to apply only to a specific tag and below. This is a tricky one, usually frameworks will handle that, react with [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), angular with view encapsulation, but it is possible with postcss or sass.
3. [Prefix the tailwind config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) with each team unique string, if they build separated tailwind output CSS.

Comment: Thank you @Ricardo Silva.  Solution 3) is not feasible as it requires you to also write the tailwindCSS classes using that prefix, which defeats entirely the TW purpose (having to start writing prefix-text-color, prefix-bg-colo, etc). Solution 1) AFAIK doesn't really solve the clash, it just allows your to set a priority but clashes will still happen, you would only be in control of the ordering.
It seems Solution 2) is the only one working, using CSS Modules in React/Vue allows for correct scoping, but requires a large refactoring from the UI Component library side of things.

Comment: You can do scoping with sass as well. But it will require your tailwind output to be imported as a partial and wrapped within a scoping tag (probably an ID or attribute). But yes CSS modules would be best approach imo as well.